# Tensorflow serving in Go

Tags: go, tensorflow

I am trying to run a keras model in Go. First I train the model in python:

```
import keras as krs
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
K._LEARNING_PHASE = tf.constant(0)
K.set_learning_phase(0)

m1 = krs.models.Sequential()
m1.Add(krs.layers.Dense(..., name="inputNode"))
...
m1.Add(krs.layers.Dense(..., activation="softmax", name="outputNode"))
m1.compile(...)
m1.fit(...)
```

Then I understand that it is advised that the model is frozen - to convert  placeholder to constants.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '.', 'my_model.pbtxt')
saver.save(sess, save_path="my_model.ckpt")

from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph
from tensorflow.python.tools import optimize_for_inference_lib

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph = 'my_model.pbtxt',  input_saver = "",
                 input_binary = False, input_checkpoint = "my_model.ckpt", output_node_names = "outputNode/Softmax",
                 restore_op_name = "save/restore_all", filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0",
                 output_graph = "frozen_my_model.pb", clear_devices = True, initializer_nodes = "")
```

When trying to use the frozen model in Golang:

```
model, err := tf.LoadSavedModel("frozen_my_model.pb", []string{"serve"}, nil)
```

It returns an error that the tag serve is not found `SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: fail.`

My questions are therefore:

1. How do you freeze a model in python, then load it in Go
2. I do this to speed up inference in Go - is it correct that freezing
   models will improve inference speed?
3. I have noted that another function exists `optimize_for_inference`, how would this implemented in the above setting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to "tag" the trained model, using

```
    # Create a builder to export the model
    builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("export")
    # Tag the model in order to be capable of restoring it specifying the tag set
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ["tag"])
    builder.save()
```

After that, you can load it in Go.

However, a more handy solution is to use [tfgo](https://github.com/galeone/tfgo)

As you can see in the README, there's the code for both: train in python and inference in Go.
I'll report here for you:

#### Python: train LeNet on MNIST (example)

```
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
from dytb.inputs.predefined.MNIST import MNIST
from dytb.models.predefined.LeNetDropout import LeNetDropout
from dytb.train import train

def main():
    """main executes the operations described in the module docstring"""
    lenet = LeNetDropout()
    mnist = MNIST()

    info = train(
        model=lenet,
        dataset=mnist,
        hyperparameters={"epochs": 2},)

    checkpoint_path = info["paths"]["best"]

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Define a new model, import the weights from best model trained
        # Change the input structure to use a placeholder
        images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), name="input_")
        # define in the default graph the model that uses placeholder as input
        _ = lenet.get(images, mnist.num_classes)

        # The best checkpoint path contains just one checkpoint, thus the last is the best
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_path))

        # Create a builder to export the model
        builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder("export")
        # Tag the model in order to be capable of restoring it specifying the tag set
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, ["tag"])
        builder.save()

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

## Go: inference

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        tg "github.com/galeone/tfgo"
        tf "github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go"
)

func main() {
        model := tg.LoadModel("test_models/export", []string{"tag"}, nil)

        fakeInput, _ := tf.NewTensor([1][28][28][1]float32{})
        results := model.Exec([]tf.Output{
                model.Op("LeNetDropout/softmax_linear/Identity", 0),
        }, map[tf.Output]*tf.Tensor{
                model.Op("input_", 0): fakeInput,
        })

        predictions := results[0].Value().([][]float32)
        fmt.Println(predictions)
}
```